# Converting an array from one shape to another?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape, pixel

I have a video i.e image sequences saved in an array. The output is:

```
Output:
(13,9,9)
```

Where the 13 represents the 13 image sequences and the two 9's represent the pixels. I wish to convert the array into an output like:

```
Output:
(81,13)
```

Where the 81 represents the 81 pixel instances and the 13 is capturing the time domain i.e. the video frames in time. I will then be feeding this into my CNN.

Does anyone have any suggestions? As using `array.reshape(81,13)` of course doesn't work.

Comment: I wonder if numpy.transpose() is part of the answer.  In any event, it might help if you can add a little code to the question, maybe building a toy array along with the reshape you have tried, and how you produce the Output you show.

Comment: Will you always have size of three in your array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `x` is the original video 3D array, you need this to convert it to the desired 2D array:

```py
import numpy as np
x2d = x.transpose(1, 2, 0).reshape(-1, x.shape[0])
```

This also works:

```
x2d = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1).T
```

Essentially the concept is to reshape or transpose the array in such a way that the elements you want in a row should end up in contiguous memory locations.

Comment: Thank you so so much! @swag2198

Comment: @Harriet Treacy: Happy to help! If it really helped you, you can also consider [upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)! :)

Comment: Just did! Cheers :) @swag2198